# Cannot import leaflet into TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I tried to use `leaflet` within my TypeScript-project. So I have this code in my `MyApp.ts`-file:

```
import { L } from 'leaflet';
```

I installed `leaflet` via the [VS-Package-Installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.PackageInstaller) by rightclick on the project--> Quick Install package.

However I get this error:

> Error TS2305  (TS) Module '"MyApp/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index"' has no exported member 'L'.

This is my `package.json`-file:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.32",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.5.8",
    "d3": "^5.15.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "leaflet-geosearch": "^2.7.0"
  }
}
```

I get the same error for the forementioned dependencies also. I already deleted the `node-modules`-filder from my project-directory to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import * as L from 'leaflet';` is what you want I believe.

Check out the [definitleytyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/leaflet) for it.

Comment: Now I got it. I don´t really understand the problem, though. What is the difference here?

Comment: @HimBromBeere basically the one you had says there is some exported variable `L` (`export const L = "foo"`). There is no such thing. The one I gave you says take everything that's exported from the module and stick it in an Object called `L`.